# Populate collectionView from JSON image url swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, uicollectionview

I want to Load image using JSON parsing in collectionView. I'm getting array of image URLs, but images are not shown on `UIImageView`. I have used this code after getting JSON array and displaying it in `UICollectionView`'s `UIImageView`.

```
    if let url = NSURL(string: self.Products[indexPath.row].image) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
            cell.product_image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            cell.product_image.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to load image, but text is displayed. I have used this code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.. Can anyone suggest me what am I doing wrong?

```
func jsonParsingFromURL(){
        // 1
        let reposURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.room2shop.com/api/product/GetProducts?categoryId=24&filter=2&pageNumber=1")
        // 2
        if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
            // 3
            do
            {
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: .AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                    // 4
                    if let reposArray = json["ProductList"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                        // 5
                        for item in reposArray {
                            Products.append(ProductList(json: item))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")

            }
        }
    }
```

This is my JSON parsing code

Comment: are you ever doing a `self.collectionView?.reloadData()`   ???

Comment: no.. I am not doing that

Answer (score 1):

to reflect changes, you need to use

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

EDIT

1- please replace this block with this, and tell me if you get the urls normally, for me I get the urls normally

```
                for item in reposArray
                {
                    //ProductList(json: item)
                    //Products.append(ProductList(json: item))
                    //print(item)
                    print("__________")
                    print(item["Image"]!)

                }
```

2- i was getting

Transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP

solution was here.
[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http#)

Comment: try after Products.append(ProductList(json: item))

Comment: No.. images are still not loaded

Comment: i will try it on a project.

Comment: what is the data type of Products variable ? and how are you initializing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107736/discussion-between-riddhi-shah-and-deyaeldeen).

Comment: I am trying to use Haneke library for loading images. Is it necessary to download image from URL or Can I load image directly from URL?? How can I use this library??

Answer (score 1):

> use this

```
// taking the URL , then request image data, then assigne UIImage(data: responseData)
            let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "www.example.com/image.jpg")!
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data,response,error) -> Void in
                if ( error == nil && data != nil ) {
                    func display_image() {
                    // imageView.post.image = your UIImage  
                    self.imageViewPost.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            // end of loading img
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is a URL which is not saved locally inside the `image.xassets`, so you need to parse the URL using the extension given below.

// add the extension

```swift
extension UIImageView {

    func loadImage(urlString: String)  {
        let url =  URL(string: urlString)!
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, respones, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }


        }).resume()

    }
}
```

// call this statement in your vc (where you polpulate)

```swift
yourImageView.loadImage(urlString:yourUrl)
```